# passing csv file to Ruby using JS and html's input File API

Tags: javascript, ruby, csv

I'm trying to build basic CSV editor which uses html+css as a UI, and Ruby doing the string parsing and manipulation.

```
function passFileToRuby (f) {

var     reader = new FileReader(),
        txt

reader.readAsText(f);
txt = reader.result

return txt

}
```

and some html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CSVEditor!</h1>
    <form action="/form" method="post">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="input" onchange="passFileToRuby(this.files[0])">
          <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to load a csv file via html form, pass it to Ruby (Sinatra) which will split it and render it as table content.

When I load a file and then enter the contents of passFileToRuby() line after line everything seems to work - console.log(txt) prints the contents of the file to the screen. When I pass it to onchange attribute as a passFileToRuby function however, it returns nothing, txt is null.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file might not be loaded yet when the `input` changes - it's too soon. When you access from the console, the browser has had the time to upload the contents.

Try attaching a `loaded` event handler to reader instead of accessing its `result` directly.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(evt) {
  handleText(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(f);
```

and implement `handleText` appropriately.

Comment: Alas, I have no idea what handleText should do, I've only began working with JS couple of days ago :(